SSLHandshakeException during Gradle Build for React Native App on Windows
I am encountering an SSLHandshakeException while trying to build and install a React Native app using Gradle on my Windows machine. The error occurs when Gradle attempts to resolve dependencies. Here are the details of the error:
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'app_name'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.
   > javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 12s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  
What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'app_name'. > Could not determine the dependencies of task ':gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'. > javax.net.ssl.
SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more
help at https://help.gradle.org. 

BUILD FAILED in 12s.

I verified that my internet connection is stable, Executed the build with the --info flag to obtain detailed logs and ran gradlew cleanBuildCache to clear the Gradle cache but nothing seems to work.

This is often due to SSL inspection enabled on your corporate proxy.

Download the certificate of the repository hosting your dependencies e.g Google's Maven repository.

Import the downloaded certificate into the JDK truststore using the keytool command. The default truststore is named cacerts and is located in the lib/security folder of your JDK installation directory. Run the following command in your command prompt.
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore <JDK_PATH>\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias <ALIAS> -file <CERTIFICATE_PATH>


You can disable SSL verification in Gradle by adding the following lines to your gradle.properties file.
systemProp.jsse.enableSNIExtension=false 
systemProp.ssl.SoSecurityOptions=options & CompatibilityLevel=CompatibilityLevel_TLSv1_2
systemProp.systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL
systemProp.systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit


Upgrade your JDK.


